# Overlay Scroll bar

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've got a HTML page which I use some CSS and `jQuery` to produce a CSS style overlay lightbox effect.

The code can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DQaHK/1/)

resize the window height so the right hand scroll bar appears

When the lightbox appears, the parent page scrolling is disabled.

The problem I have is that when the browser window height is resized, the overlay starts to disappear into the top and bottom of the browser window, with no way to see the contents of it.

How can I alter my code, so that when the height of browser window is less than the height of the overlay div, then scroll bars show, allowing you to scroll to the top and bottom of the overlay div.

But at the same time keeping the background parent page scrolling disabled

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine here with Firefox 22.0...

Comment: You could add the following to your overlay CSS properties: `overflow:scroll;`

Answer (score 1):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LeZuse/nNdqX/. It is just a rough example, but enough to get you started.
The idea is that once you want to show your popup, you disable the scrolling on body and show an overlay container with your desired popup content.
Notice the CSS rules `body.overlay` and `body.overlay #overlay` that enable you to display everything with just `$("body").addClass("overlay");`